# Spring transaction synchronizer closing JPA entity manager before end of transaction when foreign key present

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta, spring-transactions, spring-orm

I've got a spring application that uses JTA (tried both atomikos and bitronix with the same problem) + JPA (Hibernate), and I'm running in the following problem

Everything works since until I try to use foreign keys (for example a OneToOne relationship, cascade doesn't make a difference).

When i do, then the spring transaction synchronizer forcibly close the entity manager before the transaction is finished, and when the transaction manager tries to commit then i just get:

```
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Session/EntityManager is closed]
```

There are no other logs that indicate why spring is closing the entity manager early.

I've found out that if I do a entitymenager.flush(), that solves in the problem in *most* cases, but not all.

I've got a project with unit tests that replicate the problem: https://github.com/Kloudtek/ktspring (the unit tests are those for standalone/atomikos-artemis-hibernate

Here an extract of what I'm using

```
@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "shutdownForce")
public UserTransactionServiceImp userTransactionService() {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.service", "com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory");
    p.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout","30000");
    return new UserTransactionServiceImp(p);
}

@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
@DependsOn("userTransactionService")
public UserTransactionManager UserTransactionManager() {
    UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
    userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
    userTransactionManager.setStartupTransactionService(false);
    return userTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("userTransactionService")
public UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp() throws SystemException {
    UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
    return userTransactionImp;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("userTransactionService")
public JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager() {
    return new JtaTransactionManager(UserTransactionManager(), UserTransactionManager());
}

@Bean
public JPAParams jpaParams() {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("hibernate.connection.handling_mode", "DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "jta");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", AtomikosPlatform.class.getName());
    return new JPAParams(p);
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    if (config.isJtaDatasource()) {
        entityManager.setJtaDataSource(config.getDataSource());
    } else {
        entityManager.setDataSource(config.getDataSource());
    }
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.putAll(config.getJpaProperties());
    if (jpaParamsList != null) {
        for (JPAParams jpaParams : jpaParamsList) {
            p.putAll(jpaParams.getProperties());
        }
    }
    entityManager.setJpaProperties(p);
    entityManager.setPackagesToScan(config.getPackageToScan());
    entityManager.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
    return entityManager;
}

@Entity
public class TestObj {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    private TestObj2 testObj2;

    public TestObj() {
    }

    public TestObj(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public TestObj(int id, TestObj2 testObj2) {
        this.id = id;
        this.testObj2 = testObj2;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
public class TestObj2 {
    @Id
    private int id;

    public TestObj2() {
    }

    public TestObj2(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public void testDb() {
    tx.execute(status -> {
        entityManager.persist(new TestObj3(0));
        TestObj2 o2 = new TestObj2(0);
        entityManager.persist(o2);
        TestObj o1 = new TestObj(0, o2);
        entityManager.persist(o1);
        // If i flush the problem disapears
        // entityManager.flush();
        return null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem with spring 4.3.2 and Hibernate 5.2.2
downgrading hibernate to 5.1.1 solved our problem

Comment: there are still issues in spring 4.3.2 together with hibernate 5.2.2 ex: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14676

Comment: Fantastic that did indeed solve the problem. Would you happen to know if this specific problem is bug in hibernate or a bug in spring ?

Comment: Not really a solution I think, just a workaround.  I did not look into the details, but hibernate 5.2 contains quite some breaking changes in preparation for 6.0